# How to reshape an array containg image data

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 4554 images in my numpy array `X_train` with the shape of the array as follows.

```
print(np.shape(X_train))
(4554,) # TOtal numbe of images
X_train[0].shape
(120, 120, 4) # Each image is 120x120 with 4 channels.
```

Now I want to reshape the array into `(4554, 120, 120, 4)`, so that when I print

```
print(np.shape(X_train)
```

It gives me the shape `(4554, 120, 120, 4)` instead of `(4554,)`.

I tried the following reshape method but it gives me error.

```
X_train=X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0],X_train[0].shape))
```

Error: TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the numpy.stack() method.

If you have a list of 3d matrices, you can make a 4d matrix like so:

```
numpy.stack(your_list_of_training_data, axis=0)
```

See the documentation here for an explanation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

Comment: I used the stack, but it is not working as it says that all input arrays must have the same shape.

Comment: Sounds like some of your images in the data set aren't 120x120, and if that's the case I'm not sure why you'd want a 4D array. What is the greater purpose here? Why do you think you need a 4D np array?

Answer (score 0):

To convert 2D array to 4D, try to flat 2D array first and then reshape as below , hope it works.

```
num_images = 4554
X_train_flat = [img.flatten() for img in X_train]
X_train_flat = np.array(X_train_flat)
X_train = X_train_flat.reshape(num_images, 120, 120, 4)
```

Comment: please provide a full example that can be reproduced by providing creating `X_train`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).